# How to sort list of string with number by grammar and number sequence?

Tags: python, sorting

now i have a list of string with numbers which the string is a thai language like below.

```
mylist = ['เชียงใหม่_10_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต', 'กรุงเทพ']
```

And when i sort the list by grammar key with this code...

```
import pyuca
sort_key = sorted(mylist, key=pyuca.Collator().sort_key)
```

the character is sorted correctly but the string that have the same character but different number that not sorted by number like the output below.

```
['กรุงเทพ', 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_10_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต']
```

the output that i want is like this.

```
['กรุงเทพ', 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_10_เขต', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต']
```

So are there any way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you for response, i have try with this code `natsorted(sort_key)` and the string number is sorted correctly but it change the sequence of grammar and make it goes wrong, and this is output `['กรุงเทพ', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต', 'เชียงใหม่เขต1', 'เชียงใหม่เขต2', 'เชียงใหม่เขต10']`

Comment: Could you create an english example with the same problem, so that it is easyer to help you?

Comment: To my understanding `natsorted` is a drop-in replacement for `sorted`. Try `sort_key = natsorted(mylist, key=pyuca.Collator().sort_key)`

Comment: @tevemadar i have try but the sequence by number still wrong, and this is the result `['กรุงเทพ', 'เชียงใหม่เขต1', 'เชียงใหม่เขต10', 'เชียงใหม่เขต2', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extract the digits from the end of the string and cast them to `int`, otherwise the sorting will be lexicographic. You could use a regex to extract the alphabetical and decimal parts separately, and sort with a tuple of extracted `(word, digit)` pairs:

```
import pyuca
import re

def sorter(s, c):
    dig = 0
    l = re.split('(\d+)', s)
    alpha = []
    for i in l:
        try:
            dig = int(i)
        except ValueError:
            alpha.append(i)
    return c.sort_key(''.join(alpha)), dig
```

Now if we sort using the above transformation function:

```
c = pyuca.Collator()
sorted(mylist, key=lambda s: sorter(s, c))

['กรุงเทพ',
 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต',
 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต',
 'เชียงใหม่_10_เขต',
 'พะเยา',
 'ภูเก็ต']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful but if the number that not always at the end of word like `เชียงใหม่_1_เขต`, are there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the behaviour you expect in such case? Shhould `_เขต` account for the ordering too? @Kaow

Comment: for example i have this list `['เชียงใหม่_10_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต', 'กรุงเทพ']` and i want to sort it like this `['กรุงเทพ', 'เชียงใหม่_1_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_2_เขต', 'เชียงใหม่_10_เขต', 'พะเยา', 'ภูเก็ต']` what i want is if other character in the word is the same but it have difference number(at anywhere in that word) then it should looking and order by number.

Comment: Updated, should work now @Kaow Can you update the question too? Thx

Comment: Thank you very much, this is help me a lot :D